# Class wise, student name who has max aggregate of marks

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose i have a table as follows:

```
Class   |   Subject | Student   | Marks
----------------------------------------
1       |   Maths   |   A       |   70   
1       |   Eng     |   B       |   80
1       |   IT      |   A       |   90 
1       |   IT      |   C       |   80 
2       |   Maths   |   D       |   60   
2       |   Eng     |   E       |   75
2       |   Maths   |   E       |   90 
2       |   IT      |   F       |   80 
3       |   Maths   |   A       |   160   
3       |   Eng     |   B       |   165
3       |   IT      |   G       |   90
```

I want the output as

```
Class   |   Student     | Marks
----------------------------------------
1       |       A       |   160   
2       |       E       |   165
3       |       B       |   165
```

i.e. Result contains class wise, student name who has max aggregate of marks.
How to write a SQL query for this?
e.g. for class 1, student A has 70+90 = 160, which becomes maximum over B and C both with 80.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to calculate the maximum points a student has per class, and use that as a filtering join:

```
select  ClassStudentSum.*
from    (
        select  class
        ,       student
        ,       sum(Marks) as SumMarks
        from    YourTable
        group by
                class
        ,       student
        ) as ClassStudentSum
join    (
        select  class
        ,       max(SumMarks) as MaxSumMarks
        from    (
                select  class
                ,       student
                ,       sum(Marks) as SumMarks
                from    YourTable
                group by
                        class
                ,       student
                ) ClassStudentSum2
        group by
                class
        ) MaxPerClass
on      MaxPerClass.class = ClassStudentSum.class
        and MaxPerClass.MaxSumMarks = ClassStudentSum.SumMarks
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59cbf/7/0)

Comment: The question was downvoted because the tooltip of the downvote button begins with 'This question does not show any research effort'.

Comment: @Andomar: "how hard it is" --- to be honest this query isn't hard. It's bloated - yes, but it's simple. In some other DBMS it could be simplified with `WITH` and analytic functions and would look much friendlier

Answer (score 2):

A more traditional (and so slower) approach...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM
     ( SELECT class
            , student
            , SUM(marks) ttl_marks
         FROM yourtable 
        GROUP
           BY class
            , student
     ) x
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT class
            , student
            , SUM(marks) ttl_marks
         FROM yourtable 
        GROUP
           BY class
            , student
     ) y
    ON y.class = x.class
   AND y.ttl_marks > x.ttl_marks
 WHERE y.class IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

**Query 1**:

```
select a.*, if(@prv=class, 1, 0) as flag, @prv:=class from 
(select class,student, sum(marks) as total from table1 
group by class, student
order by class, total desc)a join (select @prv:=0)tmp
where if(@prv=class, 1, 0) = 0
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2eee/15)**:

```
| CLASS | STUDENT | TOTAL | FLAG | @PRV:=CLASS |
------------------------------------------------
|     1 |       A |   160 |    0 |           1 |
|     2 |       E |   165 |    0 |           2 |
|     3 |       B |   165 |    0 |           3 |
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 That would work, and pretty fast too.  Non-standard SQL though.

Comment: This assumes there are no ties

Comment: Yes.. It only displays only top one, so if there is tie it will only 1 student.

Answer (score 1):

The correct query is:

```
select class, student, sums.mark
from (select class, student, sum(marks) as mark
      from student
      group by class, student
      order by mark desc) sums
group by class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Statement.it is works

```
   select Class,Student,Marks 
from(
    select Class,Student,Marks,Dense_rank() over( partition by class order by marks desc) Rank
      from(Select Class, Student,Max(Marks) Marks 
        from(select Class, Student,Sum(Marks) Marks from Temp14
          group by Class,Student
          order by 1)
        group by Class, Student
        order by 1)
    )
where Rank=1
```

Try this one.

Comment: FYI: This question is tagged with `MySQL` :)

Comment: Oh i did not see the tag but it is work's in `Oracle and Sql`.I don't know much more about `Mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler query, I guess. It works fine. No need of joins.

`SELECT  class, 

( 

SELECT student FROM yourtable 

WHERE class = YT.class GROUP BY student 

ORDER BY SUM(marks) DESC 

LIMIT 1 

) AS student, 

( 

SELECT SUM(marks) FROM yourtable 

WHERE class = YT.class GROUP BY student 

ORDER BY SUM(marks) DESC 

LIMIT 1 

) AS marks 

FROM yourtable AS YT 

GROUP BY class`

Comment: This assumes there are no ties.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SQL> with cte as
      2  (select class, student, sum(marks) marks
      3  from engineer
      4  group by class, student
      5  order by class)
      6  select class, student, marks
      7  from (select class, student, marks, dense_rank() over(partition by class order by marks desc) rank
      8  from cte)
      9  where rank=1;

         CLASS S      MARKS
    ---------- - ----------
             1 A        160
             2 E        165
             3 B        165

    SQL>

Here the most important inner query is for cte table. Resulr set created for this one will be as below.

SQL> select class, student, sum(marks)
  2  from engineer
  3  group by class, student
  4  order by class;

     CLASS S SUM(MARKS)
---------- - ----------
         1 A        160
         1 B         80
         1 C         80
         2 D         60
         2 E        165
         2 F         80
         3 A        160
         3 B        165
         3 G         90

9 rows selected.
```